# Linker Error 2019 utilizing template<class dataType> in a linkList structure

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, linker-errors

I'm designing a linked list that is very bare minimum cause I want to try something regarding memory. I've created linked list before but this is the first time I'm utilizing template to utilize it in other projects but I'm running into the linking error 2019.

When I copy/paste the class definition and declaration in the main program it works as intended but I'm hoping to fix this linking issue I'm getting. I have no clue where the issue is so any help I can get I'll appreciated it.

Here's my class declaration in a header file:

```
template<class dataType>
class node {
public:
    dataType data;
    node<dataType>* next;
};

template<class dataType>
class nodeInterface {
public:
    node<dataType>* headNode;
    node<dataType>* tailNode;
    node<dataType>* currentNode;
    int nodeCount;

    nodeInterface();
    ~nodeInterface();

    void emptyInterface();

    void addElement(dataType);
    void setHeadNode();
    void setTailNode();

    dataType get();
    dataType unget();
    dataType peek();
    void setCurrent(int);
};
```

The class definition is as follows:

```
# include <iostream>
# include "classHeader.h"

template<class dataType>
nodeInterface<dataType>::nodeInterface() {
    headNode = nullptr;
    tailNode = nullptr;
    currentNode = nullptr;

    nodeCount = 0;
}

template<class dataType>
nodeInterface<dataType>::~nodeInterface() {
    emptyInterface();
}

template<class dataType>
void nodeInterface<dataType>::emptyInterface() {
    if (headNode == nullptr) {
        log(0, "Attempting to empty an empty List.");
        return;
    }

    currentNode = headNode;
    node<dataType>* tempPtr = currentNode->next;
    while (tempPtr != nullptr) {
        delete currentNode;
        currentNode = tempPtr;
        tempPtr = currentNode->next;
    }
    delete currentNode;
}

template<class dataType>
void nodeInterface<dataType>::addElement(dataType dataValue) {
    if (headNode == nullptr) {
        headNode = new(std::nothrow) node<dataType>;
        if (headNode == nullptr) {
            log(2, "Couldn't create new node.");
            return;
        }
        headNode->data = dataValue;
        headNode->next = nullptr;

        currentNode = headNode;
        tailNode = headNode;
        nodeCount++;
        return;
    }

    currentNode = tailNode;
    currentNode->next = new(std::nothrow) node<dataType>;
    if (currentNode->next == nullptr) {
        log(2, "Couldn't create new node.");
        return;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode->next;

    currentNode->data = dataValue;
    currentNode->next = nullptr;

    tailNode = currentNode;
    nodeCount++;
    return;
}

template<class dataType>
void nodeInterface<dataType>::setHeadNode() {
    currentNode = headNode;
}

template<class dataType>
void nodeInterface<dataType>::setTailNode() {
    currentNode = tailNode;
}

template<class dataType>
dataType nodeInterface<dataType>::get() {
    if (currentNode == nullptr) {
        log(1, "Attempting to obtain a value of a nullNode.");
        return NULL;
    }

    dataType temp;
    temp = currentNode->data;

    currentNode = currentNode->next;
    return temp;
}

template<class dataType>
dataType nodeInterface<dataType>::unget() { //data structure isn't meant to act as a two dimensional list. This is for the odd case.
    if (currentNode == headNode) {
        log(0, "Attempting to unget at headNode. Returning value of head.");
        return currentNode->data;
    }


    node<dataType>* tempCurrent;

    tempCurrent = currentNode;
    currentNode = headNode;

    while (currentNode.next != tempCurrent)
        currentNode = currentNode->next();

    return currentNode->data;
}

template<class dataType>
dataType nodeInterface<dataType>::peek() {
    if (currentNode == nullptr) {
        log(0, "Attempting to peek from a nullNode.");
        return NULL;
    }

    return currentNode->data;
}

template<class dataType>
void nodeInterface<dataType>::setCurrent(int index) {
    if (index > nodeCount) {
        log(2, "Attempting to move currentNode to nonexisting index.");
        return;
    }

    currentNode = headNode;
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you defined the template in the header and not a .cpp file. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: what is 2019? Please include the error message in the question